# using XmlReader to get child nodes without knowing their names(in .net)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

How do I get the the **top level child nodes(unknownA)** of root node with `XmlReader` in .net? Because their names are **unknown**, `ReadToDescendant(string)` and `ReadToNextSibling(string)`won't work.

```
<root>
    <unknownA/>
    <unknownA/>
    <unknownA>
        <unknownB/>
        <unknownB/>
    </unknownA>
    <unknownA/>
    <unknownA>
        <unknownB/>
        <unknownB>
            <unknownC/>
            <unknownC/>
        </unknownB>
    </unknownA>
    <unknownA/>
</root>
```

Comment: When you say "get the nodes" what do you mean?  Are you just trying to get just the element names, or all the content of each node or what?  Also, have you considered using something like [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387085(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of using XmlReader directly?  It is much easier to work with.

Comment: @BrianRogers I'm doing a nested deserialization. Yes I considered about `XmlDocument`. But `XmlReader` is more efficient right?

Comment: Are you looking for [`XmlReader.Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.skip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Depends-- how big is your XML?  If it is small, it won't matter.  If it is large you can still use `XElement` in conjunction with an XmlReader to stream through the XML with a very small memory footprint.  See the remarks and example code for the [XNode.ReadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @dbc Thanks! I used `Skip()` at last.

Answer (score 1):

You can walk through the file using [`XmlReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx), checking the current [`Depth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.depth(v=vs.110).aspx) against the initial depth, until reaching an element end at the initial depth, using the following extension method:

```
public static class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadChildElementNames(this XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (xmlReader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && !xmlReader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            var depth = xmlReader.Depth;
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.Depth == depth + 1 && xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    yield return xmlReader.Name;
                else if (xmlReader.Depth == depth && xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool ReadToFirstElement(this XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (xmlReader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        while (xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
            if (!xmlReader.Read())
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then it could be used as follows:

```
        var xml = GetXml(); // Your XML string

        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            xmlReader.ReadToFirstElement();
            var names = xmlReader.ReadChildElementNames().ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", names));
        }
```